# Combining jQuery Portlets

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

it might sound weird when I post this, How do i combine [jQuery UI Portlet](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets)

Currently when the user drags widgets between columns, it gets sorted, What I am looking at is when the user drags a widget to the center of another widget, these 2 widgets should get combined. Know this is pretty weird, but looking at someone to guide as to where I should be starting at ??
Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by combined, there is a number of ways they can be combined, they are grouped together anyways, otherwise, add more portal wrappers, user start, stop, beforeStop events to manipulate it and read them, and don't skip lines

Comment: What i meant is, the two widgets get combined to form one widget. Currently I am not bothered about the content in the newly formed widget. In my case how do i know the dragged widget is center to the widget or not, so that I can combine these two widgets.

Comment: why don't you just have a button, above the two say `combine with` then combine them manually, it's just too difficult to explain, but you must gather the current dragged position, with the position of the dropped and then extract accordingly to their position, or use a droppable option of you have any,

Comment: I was able to do it using an option called 'tolerance'. This was available with jQuery Droppable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use tolerance to check whether the div is within dropped div or not

```
$( ".column" ).droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        tolerance: 'fit',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
        }
    });
```